# How to insert a new node at any given position in linked list?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Kindly check my code below. I am not getting the actual output when I run this program.

What I want to do is to insert a new node at the position entered by the user. I have tested this code by entering 5 values for 5 nodes i.e `1,2,3,4,5` and then I entered position `2` to insert a value `8`, but when I display it, it gives all other values except the value that I entered at the specific position.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
};

int main()
{
    int choice, pos, count = 0, i = 1;
    Node* head, *newnode, *temp;
    head = 0;

    do
    {
        count++;
        newnode=new Node();
        cout<<"Enter data:";
        cin>>newnode->data;
        newnode->next=0;
        if(head==0)
            head=temp=newnode;
        else 
        {
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp=newnode;
        }
        cout<<"Do you want to create a new node... press 0 for no and 1 yes:";
        cin>>choice;
    }while(choice==1);

    cout<<"Enter position:";
    cin>>pos;
    if(pos>count)
    {
        cout<<"Invalid position\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        temp=head;
        while(i<pos)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"Enter data you want to insert:";
        newnode=new Node();
        cin>>newnode->data;
        newnode=temp->next;
        temp->next=newnode; 
    }

    temp=head;

    while(temp!=0)
    {
        cout<<temp->data;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do `newnode=temp->next;` you lose the node just created. Perhaps this should be `newnode->next=temp->next;`?

Comment: Make a `class List` that contains the `class Node` and has a method `insert` and at a minimum a `Node *head;`. Having an `operator<<` that prints the `List` is also a good idea. `Node` should also have a constructor that ensures `data` and `next` are always initialized. Don't create a uninitialized Node. Read the user input into a temporary variable and call `List::insert` with it. The new `Node` should be created inside the `List::insert` function. My recommendation for the `Node` constructor is `Node(const Node *&prev, int data_) : data(data_), next(prev) { prev = this; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
cout<<"Enter data you want to insert:";
newnode=new Node();
cin>>newnode->data;
newnode=temp->next;
temp->next=newnode;
```

`newnode=temp->next` makes `newnode` equal to 0, then `temp->next=newnode` makes `temp->next` equal to zero.

Perhaps you meant to write `newnode->next = temp->next` instead?